# i cannot get rid \xa0 in this string using python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

here is the code:

```
shipping_info = u'Expedited (2-3 Bus. Days)\xa0($17.99)'
```

I cannot get it to replace \xa0 using the method like replace.

here is what i tried:

```
 x.replace('\\xa0', ' ')
 x.replace(')\xa0(', " ")
 x.replace(unichr(160), " ")
```

Comment: Remember that `replace` doesn't work in-place, you have to assign the result. `x = x.replace(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify `u'\xa0'` using unicode literal:

```
>>> shipping_info = u'Expedited (2-3 Bus. Days)\xa0($17.99)'
>>> shipping_info.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
u'Expedited (2-3 Bus. Days) ($17.99)'
```

Comment: `u'...'` v.s. `'...'`

Comment: have you tried this in ipython? i have tried this..does not work..? could you try?

Comment: @slopeofhope, As Mark Ransom commented, `str.replace` returns a replaced string. It does not replace the original string in-place.  If you want to be changed, assign back the returned string: `shipping_info = shipping_info.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')`